# How to get Execution details through API Calls in Rundeck

Tags: api, rundeck

I am trying to create a dashboard, for which i am getting all the details using API in Rundeck

and then want to write the data in Csv File,

here is an example trying to fetch data for weekly basis, which is not working [ error msg: `{"error":true,"apiversion":35,"errorCode":"api.error.invalid.request","message":"Invalid API Request: /api/35/executions/1w"}`],kindly let me know what am i doing wrong to fetch details on weekly, monthly and daily basis

format

```
#!/bin/sh
protocol="http" 
rdeck_host="machinexyz.local" 
rdeck_port="4440" 
rdeck_api="35" 
rdeck_token="token" 
rdeck_project="projectRun" 
xy="1w" 

curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/$xy" \ 
--header "Accept: application/json" \ 
--header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#execution-query) you could use the `recentFilter` parameter on your API call, I did an example (at the end I added the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command to "beautify" the default output):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="ni28E9M5s5H0s3kyCKQ0tbfPCI8jNZS1"

# specific api call info
rdeck_project="ProjectEXAMPLE"
time="1h"

# api call
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/executions?recentFilter=$time" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq
```

Output:

```json
{
  "paging": {
    "count": 2,
    "total": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "max": 20
  },
  "executions": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/execution/2",
      "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/2",
      "status": "succeeded",
      "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
      "executionType": "scheduled",
      "user": "admin",
      "date-started": {
        "unixtime": 1608296400032,
        "date": "2020-12-18T13:00:00Z"
      },
      "date-ended": {
        "unixtime": 1608296400374,
        "date": "2020-12-18T13:00:00Z"
      },
      "job": {
        "id": "f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9",
        "averageDuration": 590,
        "name": "HelloWorld",
        "group": "",
        "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
        "description": "",
        "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/job/f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9",
        "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9"
      },
      "description": "echo \"hi\"",
      "argstring": null,
      "serverUUID": "94ac86b1-56e9-4bc3-9a4c-50cd7c8a5b59",
      "successfulNodes": [
        "localhost"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/execution/1",
      "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/1",
      "status": "succeeded",
      "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
      "executionType": "scheduled",
      "user": "admin",
      "date-started": {
        "unixtime": 1608295800075,
        "date": "2020-12-18T12:50:00Z"
      },
      "date-ended": {
        "unixtime": 1608295800914,
        "date": "2020-12-18T12:50:00Z"
      },
      "job": {
        "id": "f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9",
        "averageDuration": 590,
        "name": "HelloWorld",
        "group": "",
        "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
        "description": "",
        "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/job/f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9",
        "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9"
      },
      "description": "echo \"hi\"",
      "argstring": null,
      "serverUUID": "94ac86b1-56e9-4bc3-9a4c-50cd7c8a5b59",
      "successfulNodes": [
        "localhost"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @MegaDrive68K, This was very helpful.